# Purchaseorder method payment dont' write on database

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, purchase-order

When I shop at my store and using purchaseorder payment method, what happens is that sometimes Magento writes the data in the database and sometimes does not write. I do not know why this is happening. I'm using fake credit cards to do tests. Can anyone help me understand?

[image]